# Spring OAuth2 Rest exception swallows HttpResponse code

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, apache-commons-httpclient

Restservice I am invoking using oauth2resttemplate returns a response with status code 403. I see that in my ClientHttpRequestInterceptor log lines injected to the resttemplate.

This is the interceptor to intercept request and response. traceResponse() logs response status code as 403 which I expected.

```
public class RequestInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {
    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
        try
        {
            traceRequest(request, body);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            ManagerLog.alertLog("Exception occurred", e);
        }
        ClientHttpResponse response = execution.execute(request, body);
        traceResponse(response);
        return response;
    }

    private void traceRequest(HttpRequest request, byte[] body) throws Exception {
        ManagerLog.infoLog("===========================request begin================================================");
        ManagerLog.infoLog("URI          : "+request.getURI());
        ManagerLog.infoLog("Method       : "+request.getMethod());
        ManagerLog.infoLog("Headers      : "+request.getHeaders() );
        ManagerLog.infoLog("Request body : "+new String(body, "UTF-8"));
        ManagerLog.infoLog("==========================request end================================================");
    }

    private void traceResponse(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        ManagerLog.infoLog("============================response begin==========================================");
        ManagerLog.infoLog("Response Status code  : "+ response.getStatusCode());
        ManagerLog.infoLog("Response Status text  : "+ response.getStatusText());
        ManagerLog.infoLog("Response Headers      : "+ response.getHeaders());
        // ManagerLog.infoLog("Response body         : "+ StreamUtils.copyToString(response.getBody(), Charset.defaultCharset()));
        ManagerLog.infoLog("=======================response end=================================================");

    }
}
```

But down here I see 400 instead of 403. But I see in the spring source code it is actually hardcoded to 400 in parent class(OAuth2Exception.java) of InvalidGrantException.

```
try{
objectResponseEntity = oauth2RestTemplate.exchange(url, httpMethod, httpEntity, pojo) -- throws an InvalidGrantException
} catch (HttpStatusCodeException e)
{
...
} catch(InvalidGrantException e)
{
  errorCode = e.getHttpErrorCode(); -- was expecting 403 but returning 400
...
}
```

Any idea on how to get the actual http response code from the exception?